# How to allow Youtube videos inside iFrame

Tags: phoenix-framework

I'm trying to show a Youtube video inside an iFrame.
I know I have to change the X-Frame-options using:

```
def put_secure_browser_headers(conn, _opts \\ []) do
    merge_resp_headers(conn, [
      {"x-frame-options", "ALLOW-FROM https://www.youtube.com"},
      {"x-xss-protection", "1; mode=block"},
      {"x-content-type-options", "nosniff"}
    ])
end
```

I've tried to use it inside my Controller but I'm not achieving it.
What's the proper way of using it?

Comment: Please can you provide the iframe URL that you are trying to embed?

Comment: `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ReOTXMh8wto#t=12`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error you are seeing is coming from YouTube, there is no way to embed the URL https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ReOTXMh8wto#t=12 inside of an iframe. This is provided by the browser, there is no way to bypass it in a framework.

However, YouTube provides a separate embed url that you can use:

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/ReOTXMh8wto" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

You can find this URL by going to "Share -> Embed" on any YouTube video.

Comment: That's it. Thanks Gazler. And if I want to allow it for only some routes? Where should I put the code that changes the X-Frame-options?

Comment: You don't need to set the X-Frame-options - YouTube set that. It is a property that prevents their pages from being embedded in an iframe.

Comment: Right! I just tried without it and is working like you say. But, as I though it was an X-Frame-options issue, if I had to change them was I doing it right?

Comment: You didn't have to change the X-Frame-Options. You needed to use a YouTube page which didn't have the X-Frame-Options `DENY` or `SAMEORIGIN` set. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/X-Frame-Options

Comment: @Paulo: When you set an `X-Frame-Options` header for your resources on your end, then that influences how/if _your_ resources can be embedded via (i)frames by other people on _their_ sites. But you can of course not override Youtube’s decision in that regard by setting the header on your end – YT would have to do that.